# Not possible to build electron package correctly in windows server machine(tfs agent)

Tags: tfs, electron

I build application using electron framework, I see package is correctly in my local machine(windows 10 64 bit). After the package is built, I am able to run the package.

If I run the application in windows server 2019, I cannot run the application that is built.

More Info, I build the electron package in tfs and the tfs agent is windows server 2019.

Build script inside package.json

"builder": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname MGCenter . --executable-name ClientLMCenter  --no-prune --asar"

Comment: So what do you see? Any errors? Missing assemblies? What's the difference between your local output and that of the build server?

Comment: I see some assemblies are missing, whole package size is reduced in win server 2019 compared to one generated on win 10 machine

Comment: "builder": "electron-packager --out winx64 --overwrite --platform win32 --appname clientlmcenter . --executable-name MGCenter  --no-prune --asar"

Comment: are you using the same node-version on the windowsserver as on your local machine ?

Comment: Yes I am using same node version in both the machines (v 8.12.0)